# ServerWebExchange attributes are empty

Tags: spring, filter, spring-webflux

I have Spring Boot annotation based controller built on WebFlux. I implement `WebFilter`, inside `WebFilter` I invoked `serverWebExchange.getAttributes()` and it returned 4 attributes which is fine. But after that it stopped working and now it always returns empty attributes map. I didn't change anything in controller, but even if I did I should still get those attributes. Why it stopped working?

Comment: You might have imported something that has caused the application to convert over to a servlet. If both web and webflux are on the classpath, the default is MVC. Try setting `spring.main.web-application-type=REACTIVE` in your properties to see what happens?

Comment: @Brian Hi, I debugged `SpringApplication#deduceWebApplicationType` and `REACTIVE` is chosen for my application even though I don't set it in `application.properties` and I don't have `@EnableWebFlux` annotation. Probably it's because I use `spring-boot-starter-webflux`.

Comment: @Brian https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when firstly I do:

```
this.handlerMapping.getHandler(serverWebExchange)
```

where `handlerMapping` is a bean of type `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` which you can inject from WebFlux.

This line of code initializes `serverWebExchange` attributes. In question I wrote that it worked once and then it stopped. The reason for that is that I was experimenting with `handlerMapping` at that time and it made it work, then I removed it and attributes stopped being initialized. Debugging showed that normally those attributes are set after `WebFilter`s are applied. This line of code makes it initialize earlier.